# Ubuntu 12.04 Google-earth install anomaly

Tags: 12.04, google-earth, utf-8

I tried out more methods: the result was identical. No way UTF-8 to set characters. It lsb-core and the ttf-mscorefonts packets are installed.

I cannot reach it, that it UTF-8 letters the Google-Earth let them appear in his choice.In Hungary the öŐőŐüÜűŰíÍóÓáÁéÉ characters fundamental... :(

Google-Earth version: 6.2

Answer (score 1):

Type in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install xfonts-75dpi xfonts-100dpi
```